# How to troubleshoot/install/repair Android usb device drivers

Tags: android, windows, usb

I'm a developer and have three phones, a Motorola Droid, a Samsung Galaxy, and Nexus S, and I could only get the Droid working on my current laptop.  I heard that PDANet could help, so I installed that, and afterwards none of them worked.  I tried installing the Samsung Nexus S driver, and I've tried upgrading the drivers in the SDK manager, but no matter what I try, I can't seem to get any of them working (when I type "adb devices" in command line they don't show up, neither are they recognized in my IDE... I happen to use IntelliJ, but I suspect Eclipse would not find it either).

Does anyone have any tips on how to troubleshoot/install/repair usb device drivers? (other than PDANet since I've already tried that)

Comment: is usb debugging enabled on those phones? Also, can you browse the internal storage? (Does your OS detect them?)

Answer (score 0):

You need the correct USB drivers for the devices. [The Nexus S drivers are included in the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) and the Galaxy drivers are available on the Samsung website. I assume you're on Windows; do the devices show up in Device Manager? If not, try a different USB port or machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to connect my HTC Desire to a PC and use it as ADB device. Heres now to do it:

- Using Android SDK manager install Google USB driver (if you havent already)
- Turn on **Debuging** on your device
- Open Device manager and look for `Other Devices/ADB`
- Right click on it, `Properties`, open `Details` tab, select `Hardware Ids` property
- Then you will see something like this: `USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C87&MI_01` right click on it, and `Copy`. The `VID` part will have the [Vendor ID](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) from the table at the bottom of the page.
- Using any text editor open `android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf`
- Now find `[Google.NTx86]` part of the file if you have x86 PC or `[Google.NTamd64]` if you have x64 PC
- Under your part of the file add this and paste copied Hardware ID inplace of "###":

  ```
  ; Your phone name - can be anything
  %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, ###
  ```
- So it looks like this for example for HTC Desire:

  ```
  ; HTC Desire
  %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_0C87&MI_01
  ```
- Save the file, go to Device manager, right click on ADB, Properties, Driver, Update driver, Browse... and locate the `android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver` folder
- Instal the edited driver
- Run `adb devices` and you should see your phone!